# Loading pages into php

Tags: php, .htaccess, filesystems

I've been looking around for this, and really can't figure it out. I've done this before, but for life of me can't remember how to.

So, let me start.

I'm wanting to know how to create a 'Page Selector' or 'Template System'. Thus meaning, I can have all my pages into one page (index.php). Let me show you an example:

domain.com/?page=Login - Instead of domain.com/Login.php.

Comment: I sense a question is here somewhere... but I cannot find it yet

Comment: Hi - not enough information for us to go on... whenever you're asking somebody for help and you use the word "it" - it should be an alarm bell for you that you have't explained what "it" is yet... Here's an article on how to write good questions *please* read it and update yours :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You mean a template system probably, i use this to handle which page it should load, then load in things with the function it calls.

```
function pageSelector(){
    if(array_key_exists('page', $_GET) && !empty($_GET['page'])){
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        pageSwitch($page);
    } else {
        $_GET['page'] = 'home';
        pageSelector();
    }
}

function pageSwitch($page){
    switch($page){
        case 'home':
        //code
        break;
    }
}
```

so ?page=home would go to home, and ?page=login would go to login, if you made the case login ofcourse.

Comment: Yes, sorry.. I had no idea what to call it, thank you so much Koen.

Comment: Just another question.. how do you had multiple pages to that?